# (Hibernate) Difference between Session.close() and releaseSession(Session)

Tags: java, hibernate, session, spring-mvc

I´m using Hibernate and Spring MVC on this project.

I have this piece of code:

```
...

int count = (Integer) this.getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).list().get(0);

this.getSession().close();

return count;
```

should I use `this.getSession.close()`, or should I use `releaseSession(this.getSession())` ??

I´m having troubles understanding the difference between those two methods..

THANKS!

Comment: Where does this magic `releaseSession` method come from?

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html#releaseSession(org.hibernate.Session)

Comment: Well then there's your answer: _Close the given Hibernate Session, created via this DAO's SessionFactory, **if it isn't bound to the thread** (i.e. isn't a transactional Session)._ (emphasis added). The `close` method will **always** close the `session`. The `releaseSession` method will only close the `session` if required. If you close a thread bound session then you will have problems elsewhere in your app as Spring does not expect it to be closed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks for your answer, now.. it´s ok to use releaseSession(this.getSession()) ??

Answer (score 2):

HibernateDaoSupport is a support provided by Spring framework and when releaseSession() is called it only terminates the hibernate session,not the transaction. But when you perform session.close() of hibernate it terminates the transaction as well. I think you do not need to handle these transactions by yourself . Just let spring to handle them. @Transactional will handle them. Just define it where needed.